# Заполнение таблицы БД с помощью словарей с ключами равными именам колонок

Tags: python, sql, база-данных, python-3.x, postgresql

Есть список словарей вида:

```
[{"1":"1","2":"1"},...]
```

в котором ключи словарей являются колонками в таблице БД. То есть, все словари с одинаковыми ключами, но с разными значениями. Мне надо добавить эти значения в таблицу.

Как это реализовать?

Comment: приведите небольшой пример данных и DDL (`create table ...`) таблицы. Все ли поля таблицы присутствуют в словарях? Планируется таблицу обновлять, перезаписывать или создавать?

Comment: все поля таблицы присутствуют в словарях, то есть таблица имеет колонки 1, 2, 3... каждый словарь имеет ключи 1, 2, 3... при чем в той же последовательности. Таблица не будет обновляться.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

data = [{'a':1, 'b':'string1'}, {'a':2, 'b':'string2'}, {'a':3, 'b':'string3'}]

# create SQL Alchemy DB connection
# conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@host:port/dbname')
conn = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host:port/dbname')

# create Pandas DataFrame from the list of records
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# write DF into SQL table
df.to_sql('table_name', conn, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Пример DataFrame:

```
In [74]: df
Out[74]:
   a        b
0  1  string1
1  2  string2
2  3  string3
```

Comment: да, это действительно решение моей проблемы, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Нашел еще одно решение с помощью psycopg2. Потребовалось из-за того, что pandas не поддерживает python 3.4.

```
import psycopg2

out = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}, {'a':4,'b':5,'c':6}]

with psycopg2.connect("dbname='dbname' user='user' host='host' password='password'") as conn1:
    with conn1.cursor() as cur:
        cur.execute("CREATE TABLE table (a varchar, b varchar, c varchar);")
        cur.executemany("INSERT INTO table VALUES (%(a)s, %(b)s, %(c)s);", out)
        conn1.commit()
```

Comment: Интересное параметризированное заполнение запроса :) А если у нас был список/кортеж то в executemany можно было `?` использовать?

Comment: Pandas до версии 0.20.x официально поддерживает Python 3.4

Comment: @gil9red, да, знаки вопроса тоже можно использовать. Всего можно использовать [5 различных стилей для "prepared statements"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle)